# React Native Expo ImagePicker --> Blob --> Firebase Storage not uploading

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

**Goal:**

Select an image from local storage (IOS emulator) using Expo ImagePicker and upload it to Firebase storage

**Console output:**

```
Upload is 0% done
Upload is running
```

But it gets stuck there, image doesn't get uploaded

First I call this function to choose an image from local storage and retrieve blob, the image displays fine on the screen, I get an error if I try to console log the blob saying it can't be shown which I'm guessing is because its a blob

```
 async function pickImage() {

    result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true, 
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    }); 

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      let imageFile = await fetch(result.uri);
      let imageBlob = await imageFile.blob()
      setBlob(imageBlob)
    }
  }
```

then I attempt to upload to Firebase storage:

```
 function uploadToFirebase(){ 

    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'anything.jpg');
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);

    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    setImageProgress((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100)
   
    console.log('Upload is ' + imageProgress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case 'paused':
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case 'running':
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // A full list of error codes is available at
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/unauthorized':
        // User doesn't have permission to access the object
        break;
      case 'storage/canceled':
        // User canceled the upload
        break;

      // ...

      case 'storage/unknown':
        // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
        break;
    }
  }, 
  () => {
    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
      setLoadedImage(downloadURL)
    });
  }
);


  }
```

I've tried every iteration of this I could find online but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try. I've seen the other answer posted and tried it, but it also fails sometimes. Here are a few things you can try first.

1. Add contentType metadata to your upload.
2. Storage accepts png files best. If you're able to reformat them, do that with Expo manipulateAsync().
3. Switch to react-native-firebase. It's super easy nowadays to have managed expo apps with the cli builds.
4. I'm sure it's only a firestore/realtime thing but I now remove undefined keys from anything I upload to a firebase service. Sometimes, keys I use are undefined on images, so I just account for that later on the front end.

Introducing 1 & 2 for image uploads

```
  const newImage = await manipulateAsync(uri, [], {
              compress: 0.1, //// compressing your image is also supposed to help with the upload.
              format: SaveFormat.PNG,
            });

let file = newImage.uri
let metadata = {
   contentType: "image/png"
}

/// 3. I prefer react-native-firebase. 
/// that upload would look like 
const uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file, metadata)

/// firebase v9 would look like
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata)
```

Video uploads gave me more of a hassle and this was my workaround:

```
 file = image.localUri;
            const filetype = file.split(".").pop()?.toLowerCase();
//// 1. Add file metadata
            if (filetype === "mov") {
              metaData = {
                contentType: "video/quicktime",
              };
            } else if (filetype === "mp4") {
              metaData = {
                contentType: "video/mp4",
              };
            }
            
            const res = await fetch(file);
            const blob = await res.blob();

            ///3. react native firebase
            const uploadTask = assetRef.put(blob);
            
            ///firebase v9
            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob, metadata);
```

4. Remove undefined keys.

```
///I don't think this has a real effect on storage, but I do it as a just incase measure. Do this when you're picking your image with image picker.

const removeUndefinedKeys = (obj: any) => {
  let newObj: any = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] !== undefined) {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
};

const wUndKeys = { height: 100, width: 100, orientation: undefined }

const newObj = removeUndefinedKeys(wUndKeys)

/// newObj = { height: 100, width: 100 }
```

I gave you the TLDR first,

here is my actual function that uploads to my storage bucket

```
 let p = images.map((image, index) => {
          return { progress: 0, i: index };
        });
        setUploadProgress(0);
        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          console.log(`image ${i} of ${images.length}`);
          const image = images[i];
          const id = `${uuid.v4()}}`;
          let file = "";
          let metaData = {};
          let uri = image.localUri ?? image.uri;
          const assetRef = storage().ref(
            `users/${auth.currentUser?.uid}/posts/${postId}/assets/${id}`
          );

          if (image.mediaType !== "video") {
            const newImage = await manipulateAsync(uri, [], {
              compress: 0.1,
              format: SaveFormat.PNG,
            });

            file = newImage.uri;
            metaData = {
              contentType: "image/png",
            };
   
            const uploadTask = assetRef.putFile(file, metaData);

            uploadTask.on("state_changed", (e) => {
              const progress = (e.bytesTransferred / e.totalBytes) * 100;
              const prog = Math.ceil(progress);
///This is a reduce function to calculate the total progress relative to total photos
              p = p.map((im) => {
                if (im.i === i) {
                  return { ...im, progress: prog };
                }
                return im;
              });
              const total = p.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                return acc + cur.progress;
              }, 0);

              var currentProgress = Math.ceil(total / images.length);
              setOverallProgress(currentProgress * 0.98);
              return setUploadProgress(Math.ceil(total / images.length));
            });

// this is to handle things after the upload completes without interrupting the loop
            await uploadTask.then(async () => {
              const url = await assetRef.getDownloadURL();
              urls = [...urls, { ...image, url: url }];
            });
          } else {
            file = image.localUri;
            const filetype = file.split(".").pop()?.toLowerCase();
            if (filetype === "mov") {
              metaData = {
                contentType: "video/quicktime",
              };
            } else if (filetype === "mp4") {
              metaData = {
                contentType: "video/mp4",
              };
            }
            console.log("uploading video");
            const res = await fetch(file);
            const blob = await res.blob();

            const uploadTask = assetRef.put(blob);

            uploadTask.on("state_changed", (e) => {
              const progress = (e.bytesTransferred / e.totalBytes) * 100;
              const prog = Math.ceil(progress);

              p = p.map((im) => {
                if (im.i === i) {
                  return { ...im, progress: prog };
                }
                return im;
              });
              const total = p.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                return acc + cur.progress;
              }, 0);

              var currentProgress = Math.ceil(total / images.length);
              setOverallProgress(currentProgress * 0.98);
              return setUploadProgress(Math.ceil(total / images.length));
            });
            await uploadTask.then(async () => {
              const url = await assetRef.getDownloadURL();
              const newObj = removeUndefinedKeys(image);
              console.log(newObj);
              urls = [...urls, { ...newObj, url: url }];
            });
          }
        }
        postDoc = { ...post, assets: urls };
      }
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After searching from different topics I've found an answer. The code below uploads the image to Firebase Storage

```
   const uploadToFirebase = async () {
    const id = 101;
    // this is the id of the file or you can name it
   const filename = `${id}`;

const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // on load
    xhr.onload = function () {
    resolve(xhr.response);
};
    // on error
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
};
    // on complete
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", pickImageResult.uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
});

// a reference that points to this 'userphoto/101' location 
const fileRef = ref(getStorage(), 'usersphoto/${filename}');
// upload the 'blob' (the image) in the location refered by 'fileRef'
const result = await uploadBytes(fileRef, blob);

// We're done with the blob, close and release it
blob.close();

 }
```

Note: *pickImageResult.uri* is the image result from **ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();**